# Can one fulfill Tefilla obligation in a free-form manner?

Tags: tefilla

According to those who say Tefilla is a chiyuv, is the Shemone Esrei the only way to complete the obligation?

If all one does is talk to HaShem "free-form" i.e., in English in their own words, is that a fulfillment of the obligation?

Comment: Note whether it fulfills an obligation is a different question from if it is a valid prayer.

Comment: Do you mean _daily_ chiyuv?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Menucha and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!